# An issue with deleting data

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Two tables are related as below. When I delete any user, only user will be deleted, and it's ok for me. When I delete any salary, all users related with this record will be deleted. I want to delete salary only.

```
class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Range(00000000000.00, 999999999999.00, ErrorMessage = "Amount must be between 00000000000.00 and 999999999999.00")]
    public decimal Phone { get; set; }
    public int SalaryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Salary Salary { get; set; }

}


    class Salary
{
    [Key]
    public int SalaryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Range(0.01, 100000000.00, ErrorMessage = "Amount must be between 0.01 and 100000000.00")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}


private void DelEmp()
    {
        if (abort)
            return;
        else
        {
            int selectedRows = dgv1.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
            for (int i = 0; i < selectedRows; ++i)
            {
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(dgv1.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                var emp = empSalDB.Employees.Single(e => e.EmployeeId == id);
                if (emp != null)
                {
                    empSalDB.Employees.Remove(emp);
                    empSalDB.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
    }



private void DelSal()
    {
        if (abort)
            return;
        else
        {
            int selectedRows = dgv1.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
            for (int i = 0; i < selectedRows; ++i)
            {
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(dgv1.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                var sal = empSalDB.Salaries.Single(s => s.SalaryId == id);
                if (sal != null)
                {
                    empSalDB.Salaries.Remove(sal);
                    empSalDB.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have `CascadeDelete` set in the database?

Comment: Are these the entire definitions for these entities? I suspect the cause of this is in their relationships and navigation properties. Entity framework often makes these two way by default, which is why delete from one causes a cascading delete in the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to to mark Employee's SalaryId as nullable. If its not nullable, what happens when you delete a Salary? The related Employee's SalaryId can't be set to the deleted Salary's Id because it doesn't exist but you cant leave the Id null. Salary is optional to an Employee so reflect that by allowing it to be null.

```
public class Employee
{
    ...
    public int? SalaryId { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, you can turn on CascadeDelete using the Fluent API's `WillCascadeOnDelete(true)`.

Comment: You're edit is incorrect. Since `SalaryId` is (probably) an `int` it can be loaded without loading `Salary`. Thus, you can do queries on that `int` without the need to load related entities which can be much more efficient. It will only Lazyload if you do `Include` or if you access the navigational property in the DbContexts using. `SalaryId` is always there.

Comment: @Default - The Salary property is `virtual` so therefore it is lazy loaded unless otherwise specified. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: If you visit `Salary.SalaryId` the `Salary` property will be loaded. If you check the `SalaryId` property the `Salary` property will **not** be loaded. There's a difference. Sometimes you do not want to load the related entity.

Comment: @Default but doesn't the lazy loaded property load when the principal loads? In this case, anytime you load an Employee, you're also going to load its Salary right? It doesn't load the virtual prop when you use it for the first time, it loads it when the Employee is loaded. Unless I'm mistaken - which wouldn't be too crazy for me.

Comment: It only gets loaded if you, in the DbContexts using, tell it to be included (Via the ObjectQuery<T>.Include) or as done in the link you provided (with `.ToList()`). If you do not use these methods and leave the using and then try to access `Salary` you will get an `ObjectDisposedException`. However, SalaryId will be populated. So no, it's not loaded if you do not tell it to be. My point is, if you for instance have a `salaryId` to work with and want to get Employees with that Id you can do a query against `SalaryId` (which will not load `Salary`) without loading `Salary`, i.e. more efficient.